# how to perform expensive calculations using textPainter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need layout many words and it takes a long time,it will block UI thread

What should I do?

I have tried to use TextPainter.layout in isolate,but it will get a compiler error native function not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> right now you would have to write your own line-breaking logic -
>   perhaps as a plugin. We don't currently have any API for doing text
>   layout in a separate isolate.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30604

so,as he said,write a plugin